# How to deploy workflow in Standard Logic App with the help of ARM template

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template with me but whenever I deploy that ARM template it creates a Logic app with Consumption. I need the ARM template which will create a logic app workflow under the standard logic app which I have created.

Appreciate it if anyone can provide a solution for this. I have gone through multiple articles but didn't get straight forward way to do it.

I tried with the standard ARM template but it's not working for the standard Logic app. It creates Consumption Logic App with it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Logic Apps operate in Azure a lot like function apps with a site container, containing multiple workflows, connections and parameters.

For this reason we don't deploy our individual workflows as arm templates, instead we deploy the Logic App Standard container itself via arm template, then deploy the JSON for each workflow to the container we have created.

As I understand it, workflows are read from the standard logic app filesystem, so rather than using ARM templates to deploy them, the workflow definition simply needs to exist at

```
/site/wwwroot/{{Your Logic App Name}}/workflow.json
```