# How to deploy a "Logic App Standard" with multiple workflows via arm template

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template, azure-automation

I cannot figure out how to define workflows within the arm template that successfully deploys a **Logic App Standard** of resource type/kind:

- **"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"**,
- **"kind": "functionapp,workflowapp"**

Logic App Standard requires an existing app service plan and a storage account as opposed to Consumption Logic App. I cannot find any reference or documentation on how define workflows to be created within the Logic App Standard. I have provided the logic app resource code snippet from the arm template below.

```
"resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "functionapp,workflowapp",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                            "value": "node"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                            "value": "~18"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId(parameters('subscriptionId'),parameters('resourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId(parameters('subscriptionId'),parameters('resourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                            "value": "clmslogicapp876a"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__id",
                            "value": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__version",
                            "value": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APP_KIND",
                            "value": "workflowApp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cors": {},
                    "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
                    "ftpsState": "FtpsOnly",
                    "netFrameworkVersion": "v6.0"
                },
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[variables('subnetForInjectionID')]",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled",
                "httpsOnly": true,
                "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('resourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
            },
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            }
        }
    ]
```

All resources and sample templates refer to Consumption Logic Apps of resource type which I am not trying to deploy:

- **"type" : "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"**

Workflow definitions can be found in the azure portal as json under the **</> Code** tab. I have tried adding this .json workflow definitions within the Logic App Standard properties in a resources array and the arm template successfully deploys but there are no workflows in the logic app. With definitions of the workflows and a successful deploy I would expect there to be additional resources in the logic app once it is provisioned but the logic app deploys fine, and the workflow tab is empty.

Comment: As per my understanding, if you are using resource type as `Microsoft.Logic/workflows` for creating workflows, it is failing every time? @Tyler

Comment: No, I am deploying a Logic App Standard `type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"` `"kind": "functionapp,workflowapp` and I cannot find out how to deploy workflows to it. I found a similar post lacking a solution to the problem [How to deploy workflow in Standard Logic App with the help of ARM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74799025/how-to-deploy-workflow-in-standard-logic-app-with-the-help-of-arm-template)

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Logic/workflows`is mainly suitable for consumption logic apps. There is no direct way to deploy a workflow inside a logic app standard using ARM templates. One way is to use [deployment scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template) available in ARM and the other approach is using bicep post deployment scripts.

*Your code should be modified similar to below by using ARM deployment PowerShell scripts:*

Firstly, created a logic app standard resource first and then adding a workflow with the `Set-AzLogicapp` PowerShell command in the deployment scripts resource as shown below.

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The datacenter to use for the deployment."
      }
    },
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "mynewapj"
    },
    "appServicePlanName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3,
      "maxLength": 24
    },
    "kind": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "StorageV2"
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "skuTier": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "tier": "[parameters('skuTier')]"
      },
      "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
      "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "WS1",
        "tier": "WorkflowStandard"
      },
      "kind": "windows"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName'))]"
      ],
      "kind": "workflowapp,functionapp",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6",
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APP_KIND",
              "value": "workflowApp"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__id",
              "value": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__version",
              "value": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',concat(listKeys(concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageName')),'2019-06-01').keys[0].value),';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE",
              "value": "true"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "node"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',concat(listKeys(concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageName')),'2019-06-01').keys[0].value),';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[parameters('logicAppName')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "~12"
            }, 
            {
              "name": "WORKFLOWS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID", 
              "value": "[subscription().subscriptionId]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WORKFLOWS_LOCATION_NAME", 
              "value": "[parameters('location')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WORKFLOWS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME", 
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "BLOB_CONNECTION_RUNTIMEURL", 
              "value": ""
            }              
          ]
        },
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false
      }
    },
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
      "name": "newdeploj",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "azPowerShellVersion": "3.0",
        "scriptContent": "Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroup> -Name <logicAppName> -DefinitionFilePath .\\schemadef.json",
        "forceUpdateTag": "utcNow()",
        "retentionInterval": "PT4H"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "logicAppSystemAssignedIdentityTenantId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[subscription().tenantid]"
    },
    "logicAppSystemAssignedIdentityObjectId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('logicAppName')),'2019-08-01', 'full').identity.principalId]"
    },
    "LAname": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('logicAppName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

*Reference*: [Lekman's blog](https://www.lekman.com/blog/2022/03/deploy-logic-app-standard-workflows/)